# How to seek back in JWPlayer's on("seek") callback

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jwplayer7

I want to seek back the video to specific position in on('seek') callback of JWPlayer 7

I am following this guide [**`seek`**](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/api/javascript_api_reference/#seek)

But the problem is, It goes in a loop

```
instance = jwplayer("myDiv").setup({
    "file": "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"
});

instance.on("seek", function(e) {
   alert("Hello");
   instance.seek(2)
});
```

[**`JSFiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/1jz2f479/2/)

Answer (score 0):

That's as to be expected - the call to the .seek() method will fire a subsequent "seek" event - hence you will get yourself into an never-ending loop.

What you need to do is to distinguish between a "seek" event being fired via code versus a user interaction, and then make the "onSeek" code conditional on this.

A simple way to do this is to attach a "click" listener to the JW seekbar HTML element - you can then detect that the seek was user initiated and perform your "re-seek" based on this interaction:

```
instance.on('ready',function(){
    var container = instance.getContainer();
    var slider = container.querySelectorAll('.jw-slider-container');
    if(slider && slider[0]) slider[0].addEventListener("click", function() { instance.seek(2); }, true);
});
```

You then also don't need to include the "onSeek" listener function.